# Switch between views with crossfade animation

Tags: android

I've wrote a small activity that is able to switch between two views. Now I am trying to add some animation (fade-in/fade-out effect). Can anybody explain me how to do that right?

My own attempt to do this works kinda buggy (if I will click buttons very fast, my application freezes). I use code listed below:

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity {
private boolean isLogin = false;
private String KEY_IS_LOGIN = "KEY_IS_LOGIN";
private Animation anim_fadein;
private RelativeLayout welcome, login;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    welcome = (RelativeLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_welcome_menu, null);
    login = (RelativeLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_welcome_login, null);
    anim_fadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_fadein);
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        isLogin = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGIN, false);
    if (isLogin)
        setContentView(login);
    else
        setContentView(welcome);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (isLogin) {
        setContentView(welcome);
        welcome.startAnimation(anim_fadein);
        isLogin = false;
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGIN, isLogin);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

public void onButton1Click(View v) {
    setContentView(login);
    login.startAnimation(anim_fadein);
}

public void onButtonLoginClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void onButtonBackClick(View v) {
    setContentView(welcome);
    welcome.startAnimation(anim_fadein);
}
```

Animation XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromAlpha="0.0"
android:toAlpha="1.0"
android:duration="800" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: android put some basic animations for developers to use, which can be found in `android.R.anim.` "fade-in & fade out" are in there, else you can just specify your own through xml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I have done this in the past is by using the [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) class and utilizing the built-in animation functions that the package provides.

Here is an example on how to do this; in my experience the transitions have been very smooth:

### The XML File

```
<LinearLayout
    //Ommitted...
    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/[your_id_here]"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <RelativeLayout
                <!--Your first layout XML here...-->
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                <!--Your second layout XML here...-->
            </RelativeLayout>
    </ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please note that you do not have to use relative layouts, I simply used them for the sake of clarity.

### Implementing The Animations

Get a reference to the `ViewFlipper` in your activity:

```
ViewFlipper v = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.[your_id]);
```

Set the animations as necessary:

```
v.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation([your_activity_name].this, R.anim.[your_in_animation here]));
v.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation([your_activity_name].this, R.anim.[your_out_animation here]));
```

Please note that you can find some **really good** prebuilt animations in the Android class files located in the following directory:

```
[android-sdks]/samples/android-[VERSION_NUMBER_HERE]/ApiDemos/res/anim
```

I highly recommend using these if you can - it will save you much time.

Now, if you wish to switch between the views, use the following commands:

```
v.showNext();
v.showPrevious();
```

You might have to change the animation files slightly to make sure the animations transition properly (i.e. make a fade right *and* left animation).

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's also possible to use `ViewFlipper.setInAnimation(Context, int)` and specify the animation resource directly instead of creating the animation yourself.

Comment: You can also add the In & Out animations using XML attributes  `android:inAnimation` & `android:outAnimation`

Comment: one possible and easiest way in my knowledge is to use `android:animateLayoutChanges=true` on the parent layout

Answer (score 2):

I think there are 2 main solution to this problem

- The first one is using a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) as suggested.
- The other one is to go with the solution described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/crossfade.html).

I prefer the second one cause it doesn't need additional View object in your view hiearchy and second you can have your 2 view all across the view tree. Not only in a single place defined by the position of the ViewFlipper.

Comment: The big minus of the second solution is that it is only supported from API 12.

Comment: Yeee that's true. My solution normaly is to not animate before 12. But if realy have to, then the first solution is the one.
Actiually there are others solution, using old AnimationFramework, but it's a lot of work and i prefere to avoid supporting animation prior API12

Comment: Your preferred second solution also uses a `FrameLayout` to hold the views. `ViewFlipper` is also just a `FrameLayout` class so you don't have a smaller hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

The following Method implements cross-fade between two views:

```
 public void CrossFade(View v1, View v2)
{

    Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    fadeOut.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); //add this
    fadeOut.setDuration(1000);

    Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); //add this
    fadeIn.setDuration(1000);
    fadeIn.setStartOffset(500);

    fadeIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            v2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            v2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });
    fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            v1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            v1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });
    v1.startAnimation(fadeOut);
    v2.startAnimation(fadeIn);
}
```

In the code above, v1 will fade-out and v2 will fade-in, you can change duration and offset according to your needs