# how to achieve this kind of animation in android?

Tags: android

[image: a busy cat]

tried animations for a cardview in horizontal recycler view, but no luck!!!!

```
private Animation inFromTopAnimation() {
        Animation inFromTop = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
        inFromTop.setDuration(500);
        inFromTop.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return inFromTop;
    }
```

Comment: well, that is quite complex animation. I think it is too complex for the question. If somebody wants to implement it, then he should spend few hours on it I think. There are 2 steps of that animation. First swipe shows something like short description, and second - full content. I'd use simple cross-fade to switch between that steps for the white view.

Comment: The image animation looks more complex. first swipe does just move-up animation. The second one is something like a set of move up and change width to match_parent.  I'd suggest just doing it step by step

Comment: trying with  viewflipper.

Comment: [CrossFade animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237224/switch-between-views-with-crossfade-animation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for the question, which is similar.https://github.com/Cleveroad/FanLayoutManager